# Check Geometry Type of a Shapefile Using GeoTools?

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I want to get the type (point, line, or polygon) of shapefile using GeoTools but so far I haven't found any code.  Any other Java library also works for me.

Comment: I'll grant that the documentation is none too clear, but I think you should spend a little more time using the API before giving up. In a worst case you can fetch the first row, and use that to determine what type it is.

Comment: I thought about this as a workaround and I was wondering if there was a more direct way of doing it.  Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: Get the feature type and check the geometry descriptor

Comment: Thank you iant.  Your solution works well and solves my issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
DataStore dataStore = ....; // ShapefileDataStore
String t = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(t);
SimpleFeatureType schema = featureSource.getSchema();
String geomType = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getType().getBinding().getName();
System.out.println(geomType);
```

It will out one of the following:

- Point
- Polygon
- MultiPoint
- MultiPolygon
- LineString
- MultiLineString
- ...

Comment: what version of geotools, this works? for me always return MultiPolygon, same the object be a polygon... @dariush

Comment: geotools version 15.1

Answer (score -1):

```
     private Style createStyle2(FeatureSource featureSource) {
    SimpleFeatureType schema = (SimpleFeatureType)featureSource.getSchema();
    Class geomType = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getType().getBinding();

    if (Polygon.class.isAssignableFrom(geomType)
            || MultiPolygon.class.isAssignableFrom(geomType)) {
         banderaelChapeesdePuntos = -1;
         banderaelChapeesdePoligonos = 1;
         banderaelChapeesdeLineas = -1;

        return createPolygonStyle();

    } else if (LineString.class.isAssignableFrom(geomType)
            || MultiLineString.class.isAssignableFrom(geomType)) {
         banderaelChapeesdePuntos = -1;
         banderaelChapeesdePoligonos = -1;
         banderaelChapeesdeLineas = 1;

        return createLineStyle();

    } else {
         banderaelChapeesdePuntos = 1;
         banderaelChapeesdePoligonos = -1;
         banderaelChapeesdeLineas = -1;
        return createPointStyle();
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain why this answers the question and how to implement it.