# Get layer's "Feature Type Details" using geotools

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, layers, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to do something like this:
[Check Geometry Type of a Shapefile Using GeoTools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132572/check-geometry-type-of-a-shapefile-using-geotools)

... but getting from a layer (Shapefile source) in Geoserver.
In short, how can I get the data from this screen (Feature Type Details) using the Geotools API?

[image]

I have only this, but can't go further:

```
GeoServerRESTStoreManager storeManager;
storeManager = new GeoServerRESTStoreManager( new URL(RESTURL), RESTUSER, RESTPW); 
RESTDataStore rds = reader.getDatastore(workspaceName, storeName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to iant that leads me to the right direction ( the RESTFeatureType tip ):

```
private static void styleTest() throws Exception {
  String RESTURL  = "http://my.server.ip.address/geoserver";
  String RESTUSER = "admin";
  String RESTPW   = "mypassword";    

  GeoServerRESTReader reader;
  reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);

  RESTLayer layer =  reader.getLayer("workspacename","layername");
  RESTFeatureType featureType = reader.getFeatureType(layer);

  for ( Map<FeatureTypeAttribute, String> attributes : featureType.getAttributeList() ) {
       for (Map.Entry<FeatureTypeAttribute, String> attr : attributes.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(" ----> " +  attr.getKey() + " : " + attr.getValue() );
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: I've fixed your tags and deleted my answer so as not to confuse future searchers